# How can I extract email (in a PST) from an Exchange 2007 EDB file?

Tags: exchange

I've got a hard drive image of an Exchange 2007 machine that had some mail I'd like access to.  Is there a tool to pull the email out of the EDBs in a format I can read easily?  A PST would be good, or an mbox, whatever.

Comment: Can you boot the image in a VM and use Exmerge?

Comment: I'm having some trouble taking the image (from an old sad machine) and getting it to boot, but that might be my best bet. I'm hoping for a quick "oh, sure, run it through this thing" first :)

Comment: I known an expensive solution...  http://www.krollontrack.com/software/powercontrols/

Comment: How painful is this going to be? I don't see prices, which leads me to think "very".

Comment: Depends on the number of mailboxes in the EDB, I believe it was ~2,000 for a 250 mailbox server, the product is aimed at being a backup/restore solution.  You may want to call the company though.

Comment: Zoredache, mind putting an answer on here for other visitors?  I didn't go with it, but I think it would be a good option for mail I cared more about (this was pretty best-effort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Ex2007 box around you can mount the DB and use the export-mailbox powershell. If you don't have this running already, it would be a lot of work just to extract the e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up using SysTools Exchange Recovery, which worked ok.  "Worked ok" is "got the email out".  Was it better than the other options?  No idea, but the price (~$300) was better than getting the professionals in :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to mount the EDB file then you can use Export-Mailbox Command, here is full command:

```
Export-Mailbox -Identity source@domain.com -PSTFolderPath C:\Users\Exporter\Desktop\source.pst
```

If EDB file is offline then you need to use third party tools. Ontrack, Stellar Converter for EDB, quest , many tools are available.

You can check following links for more information:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/32640-how-to-export-mailboxes-to-pst-files-in-exchange-2007

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2211539-how-do-i-export-mailboxes-from-exchange-2007-to-pst-format